# Need a jquery for collapsible div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a div to dropdown/collapse (div is open not hidden when page opens) to bottom of screen when clicked (down arrow button, which then changes to an uparrow at the bottom) then when uparrow is clicked the panel slides back up to original position. I also need the page to scroll. Like this example:

http://www.bruges-bedandbreakfast.be/eng/

I've found this similiar jquery, but it doesn't drop to the bottom of the page or take the button with it!

http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/eK8X5/7/

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This 



.container {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.container div {
    width:100%;
}
.container .header {
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}



$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
```

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Cant you just use jQuery ui accordian? As var as dropping to the bottom of the screen you would have to calculate height based on body height - the hight of your container then add the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You may need to tweak a few things but it essentially does what you asked for.

http://jsfiddle.net/ugebr81y/

essentially:

```
$(".header").click(function () {

    var newHeight = $('.content').height() + ($('body').height() - $('.container').height());
$(this).next('.content').height(1000).slideToggle(500, function () {


    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can't get it to drop the toggle bar to the bottom but I will keep trying!

Comment: What do you mean? You want the toggle bar on the bottom when it expands?

Comment: Thank you for this, does what I asked for!